# Can re ignore a lazy quantifier?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

Given this code (Python 3.6):

```
>>> import re
>>> a = re.search(r'\(.+?\)$', '(canary) (wharf)')
>>> a
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 16), match='(canary) (wharf)'>
>>>
```

Why doesn't re stop searching at the first parethesis closure?

The expected output is `None`. The search should detect that **there is not an end of line** after `(canary)`, but it doesn't.

Edit:**If there is only ONE word between parens, it should match, if there are more than one, it shouldn't match at all.**

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: The `$` can stand for end of line or end of string. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) _"Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches before a newline."_

Comment: @PranavHosangadi this begs the question *what is the end of the string?* seems like the answer to this question is either a space or the end of **a** match

Comment: @DeepSpace not sure I understand your question. `\(` matches the `(` at the start of the string. `.+?` gobbles up everything until `\)$` matches the `)` at the end of the input string. Not surprising that the match is `(canary) (wharf)`. OP's question seems to stem from a misunderstanding that `$` would stand for `\n` in the input string when it _also_ matches the end of the input string.

Comment: @DeepSpace you comment seems wrong - $ matches the end of a string is pretty clear as there is no \n in the string.

Comment: So to answer the question: there is no evidence that re is ignoring the non-greedy ? Modifier. If you omit the $ from the re then the first `)` will be matched.

Comment: @barny, yes! To add to your comment: this happens because `.+?` means match _anything_ one or more times until you find a match, _expanding as needed_. If the [regex was `\([^)]+?\)`](https://regex101.com/r/kicH9t/1) it would have matched only the last `canary` because we excluded the `+?` from matching `)`

Comment: @barny `re` does ignore it, as it keep searching after the closure of `(canary)` and it should not.

Comment: “Should not”? OP’s re \(.+?\)$ has one match https://regex101.com/r/N12E3i/1 and \(.+?\) has two matches https://regex101.com/r/IwSYF4/1

Comment: OP’s pattern (.+?)$ says “match an opening (, then a minimal number of any character ., then closing ) at end of string. That’s working correctly.

Comment: Try `\(.+?\).*[^)]$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lazy flag isn't being ignored.

You get a match on the entire string because `.+?` means match *anything* one or more times until you find a match, *expanding as needed*. If the [regex was `\([^)]+?\)$`](https://regex101.com/r/kicH9t/1) it would have matched only the last `(wharf)` because we excluded the `+?` from matching `)`

Or if the regex was `\(.+?\)`, it would have matched the `(canary)` *and* the `(wharf)`, which shows that it's being lazy.

`\(.+?\)$` matches everything because you *make it* match everything until the end of the line.

If you want to ensure that there is only one group in parentheses in the entire string, we can do that with our "no-parentheses-regex" from above and force the start of the string to match the start of your regex.

`^\([^)]+?\)$`
Try it: https://regex101.com/r/Ts9JeF/1

Explanation:

- `^\(`: Match a literal `(` at the start of the string
- `[^)]+?`: Match anything but `)`, as many times as needed
- `\)$`: Match a literal `)$` at the end of the line.

Or, if you want to allow other words before and after the one in parentheses, but nothing in parentheses, do this:

`^[^()]*?\([^)]+?\)[^()]*$`
Try it: https://regex101.com/r/Ts9JeF/3

Explanation:

- `^[^()]*?`: At the start of the string, match anything but parentheses zero or more times.
- `\([^)]+?\)`: *Very* similar to our previous regex
- `[^()]*$`: Match zero or more non-parentheses characters until the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

the non-greedy qualifier makes it match the shortest repeat -- in this case the shortest successful repeat is the entire string.  it doesn't "not match the )" because you didn't tell it to do so

you can think of the engine doing something like this (using simplified string `'(a) (b)'`:

1. start at position 0
2. `'('` matches `(`, proceed to position 1
3. `'a'` matches `.`, proceed to position 2

   - (non-greedy) `')'` matches `)`, proceed to position 3
   - (non-greedy) end of string does not match `$` => backtrack to position 2
4. `')'` matches `.` proceed to position 3

   - (non-greedy) `' '` does not match `)`
5. `' '` matches `.` proceed to position 4

   - (non-greedy) `'('` does not match `)`
6. `'('` matches `.` proceed to position 5

   - (non-greedy) `'b'` does not match `)`
7. `'b'` matches `.` proceed to position 6

   - (non-greedy) `')'` matches `)`
   - (non-greedy) `$` matches end of string => **DONE!**

try this regex on for size:

```py
r'\([^)]+\)$'
```

here a left-paren is matched, followed by a nonzero number of non-right parens followed by a right paren and the end of the string

Comment: I think the OP wants to NOT match when there is a ) at the end of the string - so your ‘try this for size’ is wrong.

Comment: @barny you know it's really unclear -- they didn't provide sample expected inputs and outputs

Comment: `')' matches . proceed to position 3`

I think this is wrong, because the non-greedy operator should make the engine stops at that position, isn't it?

Comment: By the way, never read about a 'backtrack' within regular expressions or anything alike, could you provide more info on that? Thanks